# Android | Google Maps Getting Touched Location

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to get latitude and longitude of touched location on map. I tried a lot of methods from internet but nothing worked. Does anybody have a simple solution?

**EDIT:**

```
public void onClick_Test(View v) {

    double latitude ;
    map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
            double latitude = point.latitude;
            double longitude = point.longitude;

        /* Do whatever else you want here ... */
        }
    });

    //I tried to use values here.
    PolygonOptions currentOp = new PolygonOptions().add(new LatLng(latitude,longtidute));
// Get back the mutable Polygon
       map.addPolygon(rectOptions);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare two class fields:

```
private double latitude;
private double longitude;
```

Then get their values:

```
 mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
            latitude = point.latitude;
            longitude = point.longitude;
        }
    });
```

Then use them wherever you want:

```
PolygonOptions currentOp = new PolygonOptions().add(new LatLng(latitude,longtidute));
map.addPolygon(rectOptions);
```

Try this. This will work.

Comment: I tried it but I couldn't use latitude and longitude values anywhere else.

Comment: what do you mean by *anywhere else* ?? whatever you want to do when the user clicks on a point needs to be done inside `onMapClick()`. If you want to use those values elsewhere, create two class members and store those values there.

Comment: @Dosher  You need to declare them as a public.

Comment: @Dosher You need to remove `double` data type `onMapClick` event.

Answer (score 0):

um for example,

```
GoogleMap gMap;
LatLng LAT;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentview(R.layout.something);
SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

gMap = supportMapFragment.getMap(); 

gMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener(){
@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0){
LAT = arg0;
}
});
```

LAT contains latitude and longitude